# Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Android, when I am calling axml file from Activity, I am getting the error as,

> "Unhandled Exception:
>
> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML
>   file line #1: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView occurred"

I have stucked here for 2 days and I am didn't getting the reason for error. Please help me.

I am getting error in this line,

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main_page);
```

My axml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="16dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have the com.android.support:design library configured in you project.

Comment: yeah.. it is configured

Comment: Try this Delete `com.android.support:design` from gradle. Clean the project add `com.android.support:design` again and resync.

Comment: I have tried.. I got the same issue..

Comment: Can you post your app build.gradle ?.

Comment: I am developing in Xamarin.Android. It doesn't contain gradle.

Comment: Ok then please check if your `design` and `appcompact` versions are same.Also try adding `app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"` this in BottomNavigationView

Comment: Both versions are same and after adding app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white", also doesn't work

Comment: if you remove bottomnav from the axml is it running properly?

Comment: yeah.. It runs properly...

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code of the activity where you are using 
this code: **SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main_page);**

Are you finding the reference of your BottomNavigationView in your activity 
by writting BottomNavigationView bottomView=
 FindViewById (Resource.id.hereYourIdOfBottomNavigationView);

If you are not finding then try to find and then run your code.

Comment: this should be in a comment section of question not in answer section.

Comment: I am not able to comment that's why i am writting it in answer section. For giving comment we have at least 50 reputation point,and i have not that much reputation point.

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity` should inherit from `AppCompatActivity`.
And make sure your `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` versions are same.